# No payment method showing up

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

I set up the Braintree payment method on Magento following [this][1] article.

My braintree account is a production account, not sandbox.

I use Magento 2.0.10 Community edition and this is what i see in the console:

[image]

And i really do not understand why it **doesen't** show up as a payment method.

Any help is appreciated.

---

My Braintree settings in magento.

[image]

---

Comment: It seems you don't run your e-commerce on HTTPS, can you enable secure navigation?

Comment: I have the privilege, but how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ If you are working with downloadable or virtual products you should disable the specific countries feature inside Braintree configuration, otherwise it will not show Braintree payment method.

2/ Clear your Magento cache: System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache

Comment: Alright, but how do i get the payment options displayed ??

Comment: 1/ Have you enabled HTTPS navigation and try again? For your information https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn
2/ Can you show your Braintree settings (hide your Merchant Account)?

Comment: alright, wait a sec

Comment: I uploaded them

Comment: Thank you.

Is your billing address matching with the specific countries selected for Braintree payment method?

Comment: I changed everything i saw while configuring the store to match my location, but to be sure where exactly can i check the billing adress ?

Comment: After adding a product to your cart, you go to checkout, you digit your shipping address, then you will see shipping methods and payment methods.
Is the country of your shipping address match the specific countries you setup on Braintree settings?
Can you inspect your dom in order to see what's in your html? Do you see hidden payment method fields?

Comment: Well, I don't even get to write my shipping address, in frontend i select a product, add to cart, go to checkout and on the page `http://www.example.com/checkout/`  it shows me **no payment method available**.

Comment: Is our project online? If so can you provide the link?

Comment: http://www.vikymoda-fasion.com/

Comment: @xM0nSt3r it seems you are working with downloadable or virtual products right? 
You should disable the specific countries features inside Braintree configuration and try again.

Comment: yeah i am working with virtual products, alright let me try.

Comment: Thanks a lot it finally works ! I am gonna do some payment tests, thanks again !

Comment: Perfect, happy it works!